# Run Error 2147352565(8002000b) - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the program bellow to copy values from the worksheets created by the user (till 100 sheets) and paste in another Tab on the same workbook called "Ergebnisse"
I didn't refer the worksheets by name because the user can rename it as it's own wish.
The problem is that the run error 2147352565(8002000b) appear, if the user don't create the exact 100 sheets.

Somebody knows which condition can I insert in the program to avoid this error?
e.g.The user created only 30 sheets, so the program ignore/skip the copy and paste from the lines 35 till 104.

This may be a very silly question, but I am really new with VBA, so I would really appreciate if somebody can help me!

```
'
'Insert Results
'
Sub Ergebnisse()


'Bauteilbewertung 100 Blätter
Sheets(4).[H3:W3].Copy Sheets(3).[H10:W10]
Sheets(5).[H3:W3].Copy Sheets(3).[H11:W11]
Sheets(6).[H3:W3].Copy Sheets(3).[H12:W12]
Sheets(7).[H3:W3].Copy Sheets(3).[H13:W13]
Sheets(8).[H3:W3].Copy Sheets(3).[H14:W14]
Sheets(9).[H3:W3].Copy Sheets(3).[H15:W15]
Sheets(10).[H3:W3].Copy Sheets(3).[H16:W16]
......... Till:
Sheets(104).[H3:W3].Copy Sheets(3).[H110:W110]


End Sub
```

I inserted, BUT DIDN'T WORK:

```
Sub Ergebnisse()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets

ws = Worksheet.Active

Do

 '(Code above)

Loop Until ws = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Active

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you consider using a loop that went only as far as `Sheets.Count`?

Comment: I inserted, But didn't work:                                                            Sub Ergebnisse()
       
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets

    ws = Worksheet.Active

    Do

    Code above
   
    Loop Until ws = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Active
            
    Next ws
            
End Sub

Comment: That's not valid syntax. Search on using a `for` loop in VBA; I've pointed you in the direction you need to go, but you need to put more than 60 seconds into trying to get there. You clearly can't use `ws = WorkSheet.Active` when you don't know if the worksheet is there. The whole purpose of the loop is to only use the ones that are actually present, so it makes no sense to try to use it **before** checking to see if it exists.

Comment: Does it always start at `sheet4`?

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simplistic, but you'll hopefully get the idea:

```
Public Sub CopyValues()

  Dim count As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long

  count = Sheets.Count
  j = 10

  For i = 4 To count Step 1
    Sheets(i).[H3:W3].Copy Sheets(3).Range("H" & j & ":W" & j)
    j = j + 1
  Next i

End Sub
```

It will loop from Sheets(4) to Sheets(count) and copy the values to Sheet3.

Comment: This worked really Good!!! I know it was probably a stupid question, but I am really a beginner with VBA. Thank you all for the replies ans attention!